Line Integral Notation
Let $F: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be defined by $F(x,y) = (P(x,y), Q(x,y) )$ and consider a curve $\gamma$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then, as we know, the line integral of $F$ over can be written as
$$\int_{\gamma} F\cdot d\mathbf{r}. \tag{1}$$
Now, it is common (especially in physics texts) to see integrals of the form above written as
$$ \int_{\gamma} Pdx + Qdy. \tag{2}$$
Strictly speaking, is (2) an abuse of notation? Can we evaluate the latter by simply taking antiderivatives of $P$ and $Q$ with respect to the proper variables and evaluating the resultant functions at the endpoints of the curve, $\gamma$?

No, (2) is not an abuse of notation once you learn about differential forms. The correct things to integrate along parametrized curves are differential $1$-forms. And no you can’t just take antiderivatives; what does that even mean for $P$ as a function of two variables? Answer is it’s not defined. Things usually depend in the path taken.

I feel like you may have misunderstood my question. The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus furnishes us with the result that $\int_{a}^{b} f'(x) dx = f(b) - f(a)$ - assuming $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$. From this, the notation used in (2) seems to suggest that the expression would be evaluated by taking anti-derivatives, hence my confusion.

The FTC you quoted is for a function $f$ of one variable. However $P,Q$ depend on more than one variable, so there’s no FTC hence no general notion of primitive. The only general statement we can make is to evaluate a line integral along a given path. The path is important. So something like $\int_a^bP,dx$ is meaningless; it only makes sense to write $\int_{\gamma}P,dx:=\int_a^b(P\circ \gamma)\cdot \gamma_1’$ (and as you can see from the RHS, the path is important, and there’s no overarching primitive of $P$); likewise for the other term.

I'm aware of the path dependence of line integrals, that isn't what's at issue. Suppose we make a few simplifying assumptions - suppose that $P = P(x)$, $Q = Q(y)$ and that $F$ is conservative. Does this change anything?

To give this question some context, I was motivated to ask this by undergraduate physics text in which a line integral is evaluated in the way described above - ie the author takes antiderivatives of the component functions $P$ and $Q$.

Yes if $P$ only depends on $x$ then $P,dx$ can be integrated as in 1D by thr FTC. Likewise with $Q=Q(y)$. For $P=P(x,y)$, you can certainly go ahead and find a function $\tilde{P}(x,y)$ such that $\frac{\partial\tilde{P}}{\partial x}=P$, but that won’t help you with evaluating $\int_{\gamma}P,dx$.

I think $F : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$

Show details of that undergraduate physics text rather than concluding in a vacuum that (2) could be an abuse of notation. It is not.

@aschepler you're right! Silly mistake
